# Use sed to replace complex line using environment variable

Tags: sed

I have a file: foo

The file has a line:

```
JVMDATA="$(${TIMEOUT} sudo /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_92/bin/java -jar ${JVMINSPECTOR} ${PID} 2>&1)"
```

I would like to replace /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_92/bin/java with:

```
JAVA_HOME/bin/java
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it could be this:

```
sed -e 's|/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_92/bin/java|JAVA_HOME/bin/java|'  original.txt  > new.txt
cp original.txt original.txt.sav
mv new.txt original.txt
```

This uses the sed pattern substitution s/old/new/.
Normally it is a pain to do with slashes because you need to escape them.
On my system sed tolerates vertical-bar pattern delimiters so that can make it more readable.
I suspect you're going to want to change it to **$JAVA_HOME...** (note the leading dollar sign).

Just for completeness, here's a version using the more common slash pattern delimiter:

```
sed -e 's/\/usr\/lib\/jvm\/jdk1.8.0_92\/bin\/java/JAVA_HOME\/bin\/java/' original.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: This was the right answer for me:

`sed "s|\/usr\/lib\/jvm\/jdk1.8.0.92\/bin\/java|"$JAVA_HOME"bin\/java|" file.sh`